# Exporting forge viewer scene to GLTF

Tags: three.js, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am trying to convert some isolated elements on forge viewer to GLTF I have included this script

```js
<script src="https://unpkg.com/three@0.126.0/examples/js/exporters/GLTFExporter.js"></script>
```

I am using this code to export to GLTF

```js
const exporter=new THREE.GLTFExporter()
const exportGLTF = () => {
  var scene = viewer.impl.scene
  exporter.parse( scene, function ( gltf ) {
    const output = JSON.stringify( gltf, null, 2 );
    console.log(output)    
    //saveString( output, 'scene.gltf' );
  }, {trs: true} );
}
```

but unfortunately I receive empty GLTF output like this

```js
{
  "asset": {
    "version": "2.0",
    "generator": "THREE.GLTFExporter"
  },
  "scenes": [
    {}
  ],
  "scene": 0
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure it's possible to extract the Forge scene with ThreeJS exporters.

If you want to extract your `Forge` model into `glTF` format, one of the best way (as of today) is to use the [Forge Convert Utils](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forge-convert-utils) package.

Comment: I have used this tool specially this code 
but I receive empty nodes each file is 2 kb and no noes inside it
but unfortunately I receive files with no nodes
 "scenes": [
        {
            "nodes": [
                0
            ]
        }
    ],
    "scene": 0

Answer (score 1):

R103+ THREE.GLTFExporter() is not compatible with THREE R71 (since we use a modified BufferGeometry), hence why you are getting no geometry.

Alex is right, use glTF-convert-utils.

Here's an example node.js script, with DBID filter.  Use this to filter out a sub-set of the full drawing:

```
// convert SVF to dstPath/output.glb (with zeux compression)
// but only convert a subset of objects (see filter on line 23)

// INSTALL:
// > npm install forge-convert-utils forge-server-utils fs-extra gltfpack

// RUN:
// > node convert url  guid  token  dstPath

const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs-extra');
var gltfpack = require('gltfpack');
const { SvfReader, GltfWriter } = require('forge-convert-utils');

async function convert(urn, guid, token, dstPath) {

  // Convert SVF to glTF
  const reader = await SvfReader.FromDerivativeService(urn, guid, { token });
  const writer = new GltfWriter({
    ignoreLineGeometry: true,
    ignorePointGeometry: true,
    skipUnusedUvs: false,
    center: false,
    filter: (dbid) => (
        [34044, 40936, 41095, 39471, 40933, 40939, 41092, 41097, 41090, 40946].indexOf(dbid)>-1)
  });
  const svf = await reader.read();
  const gltfDir = path.join(path.dirname(dstPath), 'gltf');
  fs.ensureDirSync(gltfDir);
  await writer.write(svf, gltfDir);

  gltfpack.pack(['-cc', '-i', './gltf/output.gltf', '-o', 'output.glb'], { read: fs.readFileSync, write: fs.writeFileSync})
}


const urn = `dXJuOm...j0z`;
const guid = `2588ca45-8487-cddf-b974-7f04179909a2`;
const token = `eyJhbG......gJHNA`
const dstPath = `out`;

convert(urn, guid, token, dstPath);
```

Remember to fill in the `urn, guid & token` with your forge details.  The script will connect to forge, download svf, convert to gltf, then convert to glb (with MeshOpt compression using glTFpack).

Comment: Yes I used it but the model converted from it entered as paremter to three.js USDZExporter to get usdz file, the USDZ is not centered well it appear not centerd on IOS AR mode, appear above head

Comment: first thing is to get the glTF.  then we can move on to the USDZ part.  You need a glTF that is centered around the origin first.
  So start using `forge-convert-utils` with the option `center:true`. This adds a parent gltf node, that centers the glTF file, with a global offset.  
However, the offset is calculated based on everything, and you want it to calculate it based on your dbids in the filtered subset. 
Do this manually (calculate the center of the filtered set of dbids using their AABB centroids),  then modify the gltf file and the parent node, with your new offset value.